# jQuery function working Internet Explorer not in Chrome or FF

Tags: jquery

I have function which gets the table ID and copies the content to clipboard. The function is working properly in IE but not in Chrome or FF.

Please could any one help. Thanks!

```
function clipBoard(tbID) {
    var div = document.getElementById(tbID);
    div.contentEditable = 'true';
    var controlRange;
    if (document.body.createControlRange) {
        controlRange = document.body.createControlRange();
        controlRange.addElement(div);
        controlRange.execCommand('Copy');
    }
   div.contentEditable = 'false';
}
```

Comment: Please post the jQuery and HTML code you have.

Comment: We can't possibly know how you function looks like, please paste code snippet.

Comment: Post some code and we'll endeavor to help ;)

Comment: This is all a bit harsh - at least give him/her time to edit their question before voting down :(

Answer (score 4):

Chrome and FF (and all other non-IE browsers) do not allow you to copy to the clipboard with `execCommand()`.

In fact, there is no single cross platform method for copying to the clipboard due to security issues with allowing arbitrary access to the clipboard.

Some sites work around this by using the flash-based [`zeroclipboard`](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/).